# Why is the efficient portfolio assumption necessary for the CAPM model?

Tags: capm, beta

One of the main assumption in the CAPM model is that all the investors are rational and they hold the most efficient portfolio for a given level of risk. What difference does this assumption make? What would change if the above assumption is not held for the CAPM model?

Comment: That assumption is necessary in order to conclude that *only beta* is needed to find the expected return, if there are other considerations that investors use then those would become additional "priced factors" affecting returns.